# BigQuery: external UDFs with standard SQL

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

Today I tried to write a UDF in standard SQL language in the Web Editor UI, and I have already unchecked the option 'Use Legacy SQL', but it returned to me the following error message:
*Not Implemented: You cannot use legacy SQL UDFs with standard SQL queries. See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#differences_in_user-defined_javascript_functions*

Therefore I tried an example of external UDF provided on the Google Cloud Platform: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions. But it still returns to me the same error message. In the following the example:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION multiplyInputs(x FLOAT64, y FLOAT64)
RETURNS FLOAT64
LANGUAGE js AS """
  return x*y;
""";
WITH numbers AS
  (SELECT 1 AS x, 5 as y
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS x, 10 as y
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 as x, 15 as y)
SELECT x, y, multiplyInputs(x, y) as product
FROM numbers;
```

Question: How to use external UDF with standard SQL in Web UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure *not* to enter the input in the "UDF Editor" panel. It should go with the rest of your query. See [the topic in the migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#functions_in_the_query_text) for an example:

```
#standardSQL
-- Computes the harmonic mean of the elements in 'arr'.
-- The harmonic mean of x_1, x_2, ..., x_n can be expressed as:
--   n / ((1 / x_1) + (1 / x_2) + ... + (1 / x_n))
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION HarmonicMean(arr ARRAY<FLOAT64>)
  RETURNS FLOAT64 LANGUAGE js AS """
var sum_of_reciprocals = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
  sum_of_reciprocals += 1 / arr[i];
}
return arr.length / sum_of_reciprocals;
""";

WITH T AS (
  SELECT GENERATE_ARRAY(1.0, x * 4, x) AS arr
  FROM UNNEST([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) AS x
)
SELECT arr, HarmonicMean(arr) AS h_mean
FROM T;
```

Comment: I thought when `Use Legacy SQL` is unchecked - the `UDF Editor` is not even available for user to select

Comment: It's possible to write some contents in the UDF editor while `Use Legacy SQL` is checked, then switch back to the query editor and uncheck `Use Legacy SQL` and attempt to run a query.

Comment: yes, looks like this is the only way to get to case PO get into

Comment: I checked the UDF Editor and noticed that I uncommented the UDF there, which arouses this error.